# How to submit a form to destination url as destination site

Tags: php, url, curl, get

I need to submit a form with action is:"**http://www.destination.com/hotelbooking**" as "**http://www.destination.com**" but I do not own that site.

My site is **http://www.mysite.com**, after the submitting, url in my browser is "**http://www.mysite.com/bookingstatus**" instead of "**http://www.destination.com/bookingstatus**".

I guess that the site force me to submit my form from a browser because if I use curl, it doesn't worked(but I need to do that with php).(***My edit**)

How can I solve this problem?
This is my form:

```
 <form name="booking" method="post" action="https://www.destination.com/hotelbooking" >
    <input name="roomsnum" type="text">
    <input name="adultnum" type="text">
    <input name="childnum" type="text">
    <input name="infannum" type="text">
    <input name="roomsize" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="booking">
 </form>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the actual url that you are trying to send to? A lot of 3rd party APIs will retrieve the data and send redirect the user back to your site.  Normally you would have to specify the redirect url, but maybe if you don't have one specified, it sends the user back to `http://www.mysite.com/bookingstatus`.  The reason I think that this may be the issue is because there is nothing in that form that would designate for the user to go anywhere but that external link.

Comment: If the resource receiving the post data is configured to only allow posts from its own domain, then unfortunately (or fortunately, perhaps, given the implications) you can't get around it; cross-origin  resource sharing policies are an important function of browser and site security.

Comment: Actually I need to get contents from that site and fetch it to get information. I used many ways to do that including curl but I can't. How can I tell the site that mysite is '**http://www.destination.com**'?

Comment: This doesn't make sense "tell a site that the client is destination.com (wich means the site itself)". If you want to fetch data you could use cURL with some POST parameters and then parse that data with simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net !

Comment: Sorry for my English. Thanks man!I tried that, but still not working. In my opinion, referer url in header sended by curl is my problem. Do you think the same?